# How to map URL parts to parameters in AWS API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to map URL parameters according to the following pseudocode template in AWS API gateway?

```
/mysite/data/results/{id}/image/{filename}
```

I don't see appropriate fields on web form:

[image]

URL query string parameters are probably for things after `?`

---

It doesn't accept curly braces freely in resources section too:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the API gateway. When adding Resources, you need to specify the path variables (Path parameters) while defining the Resources and mapping the url.

[image]

As you can see, it also supports Path variables and Proxy variable.

Comment: I was unable to add free path parts in resources section too.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply following steps:

- Per each routing, which are /mysite, /data, /results/, /image/ create dedicated resource
- Then, navigate (tap) to results resource and within actions create new resource named
  - Setup Resource Name* as id AND Resource Path* as {id}
  - Then you will see just created {id} resource. For it create necessary for you method ('GET', 'POST', 'ANY' ...). Afterwards, open method properties (just created by you) and go to "Integration Request". In the bottom find option named as Mapping template.
  - Create new Mapping Template (it can be "application/json") and then paste following snippet there:

```
    {
      "body" : $input.json('$'),
      "headers": {
        #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
        "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    
        #end
      },
      "method": "$context.httpMethod",
      "params": {
        #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
        "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    
        #end
      },
      "query": {
        #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
        "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    
        #end
      }  
    }
```

Apply the same procedure for another resource and method

Afterwards, you will be able to invoke your API as:

```
/mysite/data/results/{id}/image/{filename} --> /mysite/data/results/10/image/aws_support.jpg
```

To parse URL parameters within lambda function, you can easily apply following:

```py
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        path_parameters = event['params'] # all the passed parameters within URL will be stored under event "params" key
```

The `event['params']` format will be as follows:

```
    {
    "id" = "10",
    "filename" = "aws_support.jpg"
    }
```